# Should I check QEvent dynamic_cast result if I already checked event->type()?

Tags: c++, qt, qevent

`QEvent` has a [`type()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qevent.html#type) member function which returns the event type as enum value. Should I check `dynamic_cast` result for `QEvent*` if I already checked `event->type()`. E.g.

```
bool ClassName::eventFilter(QObject* obj, QEvent* event)
{
    if (event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress) 
    {
        auto ke = dynamic_cast<QKeyEvent*>(event);
        if (ke)                                     // <----------- needed?
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

Is `if (ke)` condition needed here?

Comment: If you already know the type you can safely use `static_cast` instead without checking the result against null pointer. This is faster approach.

Comment: @vahancho hence second checking is redundant, right?

Comment: That's what I meant. And `static_cast` is more preferable in this case.

Comment: @vahancho maybe some reference to Qt documentation/implementation? Such info should be placed in answer area and accepted :)

Comment: Have a look at Qt doc.: [Event Filters](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/eventsandfilters.html#event-filters). There you find an example which uses a `static_cast` like mentioned by @vahancho.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a commenter suggested, checking out the [Qt docs regarding this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/eventsandfilters.html#event-filters) has the following example:

```
bool FilterObject::eventFilter(QObject *object, QEvent *event)
{
    if (object == target && event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress) {
        QKeyEvent *keyEvent = static_cast<QKeyEvent *>(event);
        if (keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_Tab) {
            // Special tab handling
            return true;
        } else
            return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Because specific events will always be guaranteed to return the same type, checking against `QEvent::type()` is sufficient to allow for a safe `static_cast` to the target type. This will avoids the RTTI cost that a `dynamic_cast` would entail.